# How to intercept Hashicorp Vault update requests?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am planning to use Hashicorp Vault for secrets management. Secrets/tokens stored in my Java application can be read by multiple services. Services may store the tokens in memory.

One service is designed to update the secrets in Vault.

Once a secret is updated in Vault, I want the Java application to get notified about the change.

Does vault provide any inbuilt solution for this?

For example: Servlet Filters in Java. All the request can be intercepted using filters.

Comment: how about reading the data every x seconds and saving it in cache?

Comment: from this comment it seems that there is no native way of doing it https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/3687#issuecomment-352030819

Comment: Thanks @Amity, I think I will have to handle this in application itself.

Comment: I ask for the secret of my application startup, but I don't expect any changes. I think that you should just query the secret every time you need it. vault can handle it. if you have performance issue - start working on some cache mechanism. good luck!